# Write to existing Adobe PDF document,Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Is there a Linux program that will allow me to write to an existing Adobe PDF document?I had a form sent to me that needs to be filled out and returned.Is it possible to do this without installing Adobe?I will probably only ever do this once,and have no other need for the genuine Adobe program.

Answer (score 0):

Try libreoffice-writer
If comes default but in case you've deleted it, install it using *sudo apt install libreoffice*

Comment: Tried Libre ;It opened,but would not write.Dont have a clue what all those symbols mean.Should the write function work as soon as I open it?BTW,I wrote a new doc with Libre writer and sent it off.I will see if that is acceptable tomorrow.(Govt doc.)

Comment: I tried opening a pdf file in english using libreoffice on my machine, and i was able to view and edit it instantly

Comment: Hmm.maybe something to do with certain versions not being compatible?Oh well.At least I got to write a document with Libre.